antd V5.18 Table unnecessary rendering of the component with onMouseEnter onMouseLeave
  const [hoveredRowKey, setHoveredRowKey] = useState(null);

  const data = [
    { key: '1', name: 'John Brown', age: 32, address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park' },
    { key: '2', name: 'Jim Green', age: 42, address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park' },
    { key: '3', name: 'Joe Black', age: 32, address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park' },
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      render: (_, record) => (
        hoveredRowKey === record.key ? (
          <span>
            <Button type="link">Edit</Button>
            <Button type="link">Delete</Button>
          </span>
        ) : null
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={data}
      columns={columns}
      onRow={(record) => ({
        onMouseEnter: () => setHoveredRowKey(record.key),
        onMouseLeave: () => setHoveredRowKey(null),
      })}
    />
  );
};

My problem is that when using onMouseEnter onMouseLeave there is an extra rendering of the Table component. It reaches 200 redraws. This is very problematic when there are about 20 data in the table, the table freezes. I do not understand how to fix this. Have you encountered this? What solution should I use?
My task was to show buttons in the row when hovering.

Rather than doing it through code, you can put the opacity of the button to zero and once someone touches that table or row anything, make it one for that time. This should solve your case.

Thank you.
As a temporary solution will do. But I’m afraid if I insert some more logic there, problems will begin.
I understand this is a problem with the antd library.
